# Get the max value of a nested aggregated object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this kind of doc structure :

```
{
    "_index": "infra-metrics",
    "_id": "C4-XIIwBNCt3Y4ACckwp",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "resourceId": "e5735563-2b4c-46e9-a38d-4728a5617ebc",
      "tenantId": "d7842881-31c9-4974-bc87-7a621ba440a5",
      "timestamp": "2023-11-30T14:17:24.627",
      "points": [
        {
          "measurement": "win_logical_disk",
          "precison": "MILLISECONDS",
          "size": 1000186310656,
          "free": 173625864192,
          "name": "C:",
          "load": 83
        },
        {
          "measurement": "win_logical_disk",
          "precison": "MILLISECONDS",
          "size": 999559262208,
          "free": 554817146880,
          "name": "D:",
          "load": 44
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I need the max load of each disk of each day for the past 29 days, how can I achieve that ?

I firstly thought about making this query :

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-29d/d",
              "lte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "resourceId.keyword": {
              "value": "e5735563-2b4c-46e9-a38d-4728a5617ebc"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tenantId.keyword": {
              "value": "d7842881-31c9-4974-bc87-7a621ba440a5"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "points.measurement.keyword": {
                    "value": "win_logical_disk"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "points.measurement.keyword": {
                    "value": "lnx_logical_disk"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "points.measurement.keyword": {
                    "value": "ibmi_asp"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "now-29d/d",
          "max": "now/d"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "disk": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "points.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max": {
              "max": {
                "field": "points.load"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I only have 1 doc today, the one that I provided abov. If i run the above query, it returns me this :

```
{
      "key_as_string": "2023-11-30T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key": 1701302400000,
      "doc_count": 13,
      "disk": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "C:",
            "doc_count": 13,
            "max": {
              "value": 83
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "D:",
            "doc_count": 13,
            "max": {
              "value": 83
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

But I want the query to return :

For "C:" : 83
For "D:" : 44

I know why it doesn't work but I have no idea how to do it.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: It's because you are using `object` field type. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html 

The issue will be fixed if you will use the `nested` field type.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html
check this article for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) field type. The issue will be fixed if you use the [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) field type. Check this [article](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-nested-field-object-field/) for more information.

Here are some useful informations for object vs nested:

> Object fields are used when the structure of the sub-fields is
> important, but not the relationships between them. They are indexed as
> separate and independent fields, and can be queried independently.
> However, if you need to maintain the relationships between the
> sub-fields, object fields may not be suitable because they don't keep
> the correlation between the sub-fields.
>
> On the other hand, nested fields are used when you need to maintain
> the relationships between the sub-fields. They are indexed as separate
> hidden documents, which allows for querying that maintains the
> relationships between the sub-fields. This is particularly useful when
> you have arrays of objects and you want to query objects that match
> multiple criteria.

Here is an example for you.

```
PUT measurement/_doc/1
{
  "resourceId": "e5735563-2b4c-46e9-a38d-4728a5617ebc",
  "tenantId": "d7842881-31c9-4974-bc87-7a621ba440a5",
  "timestamp": "2023-11-30T14:17:24.627",
  "points": [
    {
      "measurement": "win_logical_disk",
      "precison": "MILLISECONDS",
      "size": 1000186310656,
      "free": 173625864192,
      "name": "C:",
      "load": 83
    },
    {
      "measurement": "win_logical_disk",
      "precison": "MILLISECONDS",
      "size": 999559262208,
      "free": 554817146880,
      "name": "D:",
      "load": 44
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
GET measurement/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "now-29d/d",
          "max": "now/d"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "disk": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "points.name.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max": {
              "max": {
                "field": "points.load"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
PUT measurement_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "points": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "measurement"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "measurement_nested"
  }
}
```

---

```
GET measurement_nested/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "date_histogram": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": "now-29d/d",
          "max": "now/d"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "disk": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "points"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "points.name.keyword"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "max": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "points.load"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]